# sort files by datecreated and remove old files with google apps script

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-apps-script

Trying to make a simple google apps script to get files by name and order them by date created. If there are more than 5 files by the same name, delete all but the 5 newest files.

```
function tryme(){
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('thisFile');
  var created = files.getDateCreated();
  for(i in created) {
    if(created[i] > 4){
      file.setTrashed(true);}
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use a File method on a File Iterator (returns from getFilesByName() method).

Here is a solution for your issue:

```
function tryme(){
  // Get the file Iterator
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('New Text File');
  var fileArray = [];
  // Put file on array
  while(files.hasNext()){
    var file = files.next();
    fileArray.push([file, file.getDateCreated()]);
  }
  //While you have more than 5 files
  while(fileArray.length>5){
    var older = ["",new Date()];
    var olderIndex;
    // Get the older file
    for(var i in fileArray){
      if(fileArray[i][1].getTime() < new Date(older[1]).getTime()){
        olderIndex = i;
        older = fileArray[i];
      }
    }
    // Delete the older file
    fileArray.splice(olderIndex,1);
    older[0].setTrashed(true);
  }
}
```

***Edit:*** I made a mistake by using DriveApp.removeFile() instead of File.setTrashed(true)

Comment: Doesn't seem to move anything to the trash.

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake by using DriveApp.removeFile(File) instead of File.setTrashed(true). I've edit the answer.